# Skip line with specific word

Tags: vb.net, loops, streamreader

I have a problem with my .txt file.
It has the same text in it except the one says "Kleur", and the other says "Binair".

I need to read all the lines in that .txt file but need to skip the lines with the word "kleur" in it.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            Using sr As New StreamReader(f.FullName)
                Dim findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(f.FullName)
                Dim Lookfor As String = "Binair"

                If findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
End If
```

But this doesn't skip the kleur lines and the code still does thing to it.

Can someone help me to skip those lines, and only work with the lines "binair" in it?

Comment: What are you doing on a line that doesn't contain the "Binair" word? If you want to apply some logic line by line skipping the unwanted lines, then read the file line by line or process the lines one at time after reading them in memory (the choice depends on file size).

Comment: The .txt file got automatically made by a scanner. And shows where the files the scanner scanned are saved. There is a "kleur"(color) version and a "Binair" version of the scan. So in the .txt file are also lines with the word "Kleur" and "Binair" and I only need to work with the "Binair" lines, so how do I skip the lines with the word "Kleur"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply some logic line by line skipping the unwanted lines, then read the file line by line or process the lines one at time after reading them in memory (the choice depends on file size)

This approach uses the IEnumerable extension Where on the lines returned by ReadLines (who returns an IEnumerable of your lines and doesn't load them all in memory).

```
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(f.FullName).
                Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("Kleur"))
    ' lines contains only the lines without the word Kleur
    For Each l As String In lines
        ' Process the lines
    Next
Next
```

But you can also use a StreamReader to read a single line, process it if required, then loop for the next line

```
Dim line As String = ""
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Using sr = New StreamReader(f.FullName)
        While True
            line = sr.ReadLine
            If line IsNot Nothing Then
                If Not line.Contains("Kleur") Then
                    ' process the line
                End If
            Else
                Exit While
            End If 
        End While
    End Using
Next
```

Finally you can load everything in memory and process from there (but pay attention to the size of the file)

```
Dim line As String = ""
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.FullName)
    For each line in lines
       if Not line.Contains("Kleur") Then
         ' process the line
       End If
    Next
Next
```